# Noun for adopting a certain technique to another domain?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I'm working on computer science and trying to express concisely that a technique usually used for end-user products may be adopted to a core system component. I'm trying to express that in this way like,

> Core **adoption(??)** of this technique.

but it doesn't look right to me. Can someone recommend a better noun for this, or tell me if I can use 'adoption' just in this way?

Answer (score 2):

**adapted to**

idiom: *adapt (something) to (something)*
https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/adapted+to

> "…a *technique* ... may be **adapted to** a core system *component*."

The same technique can be applied to this other context with little or no change to the process.

---

"Adopt to" is not grammatical.
*Adopt* is an action *by* the person who is adopting: *thing* is **adopted by** a *person*.

In this context "adopting a (new) technique" implies a more fundamental, philosophical change that might effect the entire process, as one adopts a child or a different religion.

Comment: So *core adaptation* would be what you want. Or better, *adaptation for the core*. By the way, do not feel bad… the *adopt*-*adapt* confusion sometimes trips up native speakers.

Answer (score 1):

**Adopt** is a good word to use, especially if you're using the technique as-is. However, you adopt **by**. For example:

> The technique can be adopted by the core system component. or
>
> The core system component adopts the technique used by the other components.

If you have to change the technique to accommodate the core components, then **adapt** might be a better word. For example:

> The technique is adapted to accommodate the unique requirements of the core system component.  or
>
> We adapted the standard technique specifically for the core system component.